# How to increase font size of Eclipse globally?

Tags: development, java

I'd like to know how to increase the font size for Eclipse so it adjusts the whole GUI to not look so darn small on my screen.

For NetBeans there is the --font-size switch which can be set in netbeans.conf, is there something similar for Eclipse?

(In case it's useful, I'm on Snow Leopard.)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Inside the Eclipse.app is a setting for the font size. To make the fonts globally larger edit Eclipse.app » Contents » Eclipse » eclipse.ini and remove the line

`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts`

from the file. Save the file and restart Eclipse.

Comment: This actually helps, nice one!

Comment: Great. This solves also the small size of the interface elements, like the Package Explorer. I was turning blind before... BTW, you know what's fine? I have such line in my eclipse.ini twice, one was commented out and the other not. I wonder why the did that...

Comment: In Mars it's located in Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini

Also, I found two lines in the .ini file that had this -D definition, so make sure to remove all of them before restart.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the only way to increase the GUI fonts in Eclipse on OS X that I've found.

Comment: In Neon, the .ini file is also in `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini` just like @andrewz commented. Also, there are two lines in the .ini file as well, which you have to remove.

Comment: Several items are duplicated in that file, in Neon.1 when installed by Oomph installer.-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8, -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts, -XstartOnFirstThread.

Comment: This setting doesn't change the font size with STS in macOS Sierra.

Comment: works with neon3 and Yosemite. The GUI font size increase was pretty minimal though. At first I though it didn't work. I literally had to take screenshots before/after to realize it did increase. I'd estimate the Package Explorer font went from 4pt to 6pt (from tiny to small).

Comment: There's also an application called RDM that let's you choose any screen resolution on Mac, I often use that as a fix for apps with too small fontsizes. Like setting my laptop screen to 1280 x 800 for example.

Comment: Now how can I also make the toolbar icons bigger?

Answer (score 53):

Go to Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts, expand the "Basic" folder and select "Text Font" and change that to whatever size you like.

For Eclipse **Neon**:
To Increase Ctrl +
To reduce Ctrl -
for Macs, use the command key, not the control key

[image: shortcut for font eclipse]

Comment: Does not work at all. I am using Kelper on yosemite.

Comment: This only changes the text font. It has no impact on the GUI globally as the OP asked.

Comment: `ctrl shift +` also works an was the only way for me to zoom in (eclipse 7.2)

Answer (score 10):

**Solution for Eclipse Oxygen at MacOS High Sierra (Dec 2017)**

1. Open terminal and run commands:

   ```
   cd /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1.v20170809-1435/css

   vim e4_basestyle.css
   ```
2. Add a style:

   ```
   * {
       font-size: 14;
   }
   ```
3. Restart Eclipse to apply changes.

Comment: I hope it is allowed here to remark that this solutions also works on Eclipse Oxygen Linux. The file is in plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1.v20170809-1435/css I have used font-size: 24; on my screen (since it is a bit higher DPI than the retina Macs)

Comment: In 2019 Eclipse the css file is in ~/.p2/pool/plugins/...

Comment: BUT there are mutliple css file there, which css file should i edit?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there's no way to increase the font globally. In Eclipse's *Preferences*, navigate to General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts.

*Dialog font* is the font used in the dialogs, and *Text Font* used in text editors, etc.

I don't know how to increase the font for the rest of the GUI, though.

Comment: @MichaelLange see my reply.

Comment: This is a reasonable compromise for me.  Eclipse uses so much screen estate on GUI-fluff that this is the only reasonable way to get a lot of _information_ on there too.

Answer (score 5):

For eclipse luna :
edit
`eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.0.1.v20141126-1957/css/e4_default_gtk.css`

and add at end of file :

```
* {
  font-size:14;
}
```

This will make eclipse keep same font if you switch workspaces

Comment: I've edited `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.1.300.v20161107-1827/css/e4_basestyle.css` and it works on Sierra!

Answer (score 1):

I have Eclipse installed in a Linux machine. A while ago I did a Linux update and it messed up the fonts on the entire system. All the fonts got larger. So, I went all over the place resizing the fonts for each application.

Guess what?! On the next Linux update, the fonts got back to normal. However, I had to go back and undo all the font resizing that I had previously done on every application. So, when it came time to reset the fonts in Eclipse, I couldn't remember exactly what I did. I went to the following location:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font > Edit
```

No matter what I did on this setting, the font remained the same.

I finally figured out what the problem was. I had also resized the fonts on the following location:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Structured Text Editors > Structured Text Editor Text Font (overrides default: Text Font) > Edit
```

Once I edited this setting, the fonts on Eclipse went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** For those coming from Google, this change has no effect on later MacOS/Eclipse versions of El Capitan and Mars, respectively. See this related question: [Yosemite: How do increase font size of Eclipse globally?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177298/yosemite-how-do-increase-font-size-of-eclipse-globally)

Comment: Removing the smallfonts option from the eclipse.ini file worked fine for me in Neon on Sierra. Are you sure you removed both occurrences of the option from the file?

Comment: The font size increase is very subtle. Take a screenshot before/after and compare.

Answer (score 0):

You go to colors and font and go to the java drop down and find java editor and edit the size and it should work as it has for me.

Comment: How does this improve on or differ to http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/35588/237

Comment: This only changes the font used in the editor, not globally.

Answer (score 0):

eclipse on Mac, for the font in the tools bar, you have to go to the system preference->display->resolution, and change the system font.

Answer (score 0):

window --> preference-->general-->apperance-->colors and fonts-->basic -->text font

Answer (score 0):

Menu: window -> editor -> zoom in/out