# Yosemite: How do increase font size of Eclipse globally?

Tags: macos, eclipse

Please do not mark this question as duplicate. There are some similar questions, but they are stale. They are about old versions and none of their suggestions solved my issue. (eg: [How to increase font size of Eclipse globally?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/how-do-increase-font-size-of-eclipse-globally))

I am using eclipse Kepler on Yosemite. I want to change all of my front size in eclipse larger. I am using a 1080p monitor, and it's quite painful to see those small fonts. I found a way to change the package explorer font and java editor font, but I want to change others too. I want to change the fonts in the opened tabs, outline, task and possibly all other views. Is there a way to change them globally? If not, is there a way to change them one by one? I checked "General - Appearance - Colors and Fonts". There is no way to change the fonts on those views.

Here is what I have tried:

- change the Colors and Fonts from eclipse preference. It can only change the editor's font.
- remove "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts" from eclipse.ini. It has no effect at all.
- modify "eclipse kepler/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0.v20130605-2000/css/e4_default_mac.css". I learned how to modify the fonts in package Exploer. I just need to add:

  #org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
  #org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
    font-size: 14px; /* <-- Desired font size */
  }

Modifying the css may be a way to change the fonts of other views, but I don't know how.

Comment: There is still no way to increase the font globally. reducing the screen resolution is one alternative.

Comment: I tried it, but osx looked really ugly after I reduced the resolution, so it's not an option.

Comment: Well, you can increase _all_ font sizes using _Color and Fonts_ at Eclipse **Mars** at Yosemite: just type `font` at the filter and click through _all_ list items - not all of them are very explicit (e.g. increasing dialog font size doesn't affect tabs font size). Doesn't Kepler allow all the same?

Comment: The fonts preferences don't change many of the outlines, apparently intentional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124629/how-can-i-configure-the-font-size-for-the-tree-item-in-the-package-explorer-in-e

Modifying the eclipse.ini file doesn't seem to have any affect in El Capitan.  In Mars it's located at /Applications/Eclipse2015.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini and you have to change it in 2 places.

I've tried both removing it, and also setting it to false (per another suggestion I saw on the web)

So this old trick doesn't seem to work on El Capitan and Mars.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for Eclipse Oxygen at MacOS High Sierra (Dec 2017)**

1. Open terminal and run commands:

   ```
   cd /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.1.v20170809-1435/css

   vim e4_basestyle.css
   ```
2. Add a style:

   ```
   * {
       font-size: 14;
   }
   ```
3. Restart Eclipse to apply changes.

Comment: I found it also needed font-family to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

This does work for me on Yosemite and Eclipse Neon 3. But the font increase is very minimal, I did not even notice it the first time. I'd estimate it went from 4pt to 6pt. It still helps though, because before it was almost unreadable. After, it was small but readable. Take a before/after screenshot to compare.

- Go to your Eclipse folder, e.g. `~/java-neon/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse`
- Edit `eclipse.ini`
- Delete all occurrences of `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts` (should be two of them).
- Restart Eclipse

Comment: This made a significant improvement for me, even though it's 4 years later, so thank you for that. Easy to change and clear results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. From Preferences, search for "text Font", and you should arrive at
   "General-Appearance-Colors and Fonts".
2. Click "Colors and Fonts" on left if it's not already hightlighted.
3. On the right, expand the "Basic" Folder, and double click "Text Font".

This is the default setting that the text editors and console use. It won't change the package explorer or other eclipse widgets.

While you're there, you may be interested in trying out this font. I find it to be much more readable:
http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html